# Generate connected undirected graph script

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph

I'm trying to create a connected, indirect graph with weights using Python 2.7. The following is the script I've written so far.

```
for i in xrange(0, 10):
    for j in xrange(0, (int)(10*random.random())):
        lst2 = random.sample(range(20), 1)
        j = [(i, lst2)]
        print(j)
```

I'm trying to get the following format: x y w, where (x,y) make a vertex and w is the weight. Currently I'm able to get a random amount of x's to appear when generating numbers which is what I want, however I am running into issues trying to generate my y's and keep them from causing possible duplicate vertices (especially when going for example (1,3) and then (3,1)). Below is a small snippet of my current output.

```
   [(1, [6])]
[(1, [1])]
[(1, [15])]
[(1, [12])]
[(1, [16])]
[(2, [9])]
[(3, [10])]
[(3, [19])]
[(4, [17])]
[(4, [18])]
[(4, [17])]
```

How can I keep vertices from repeating while maintaining that I generate a random amount of x's? Also, how can I add weights? I tried the following but ended up simply generating extra pairs instead.

```
for i in xrange(0, 10):
    for j in xrange(0, (int)(10*random.random())):
        lst2 = random.sample(range(20), 1)
        lst3 = random.sample(range(10), 10)
        j = zip((i, lst2),lst3)
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import random

nodeCount = 6
vertexCount = 10

vertices = {}
while len(vertices) < vertexCount:
    x = random.randint (1, nodeCount)
    y = random.randint (1, nodeCount)
    if x == y: continue
    #comment the following line if the graph is directed
    if y < x: x, y = y, x
    w = random.random ()
    vertices [x, y] = w

#just for debug
for (x, y), w in vertices.items ():
    print ('Vertex from {} to {} with weight {}.'.format (x, y, w) )
```

Comment: I'd like to make sure that all numbers including the weights are whole numbers, I tried making w = [(int)(10*random.random())+1 for x in xrange(0,10000)] however I'm noticing that nothing gets printed when doing that.

Comment: `w = random.randint(min, max)`